# Umbraco ADFS integration (OpenIdConnect) GroupSid not set?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, umbraco, adfs

I have successfully set up a ADFS integration for Umbraco 8.
I can login and so on but I cannot figure out where my roles are..

The party who did the configurations in Azure said that I can get them by the 'GroupSid' claim, but it seems to be empty, or am I missing something?

```
SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                {
                    ClaimsIdentity claimsId = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                    var identityUser = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                    var newIdentityUser = new ClaimsIdentity(identityUser.AuthenticationType);

                    newIdentityUser.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, identityUser.Name));
                    newIdentityUser.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Upn, identityUser.Name));
                    newIdentityUser.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, identityUser.Name));
                    newIdentityUser.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, identityUser.Name));
                    newIdentityUser.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, identityUser.Name));

                    var nameIdentifier = identityUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
                    var givenName = identityUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName);

                    if (nameIdentifier != null)
                    {
                        newIdentityUser.AddClaim(nameIdentifier);
                    }
                    if (givenName != null)
                    {
                        newIdentityUser.AddClaim(givenName);
                    }

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentityUser, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                   await Task.FromResult(BackOfficeUserPasswordCheckerResult.ValidCredentials);

                },
```

When the breakpoints hit those lines, I see the Claims collection..

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsId = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                var identityUser = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
```

Here I can see only values like givenname etc..

Can anyone provide me some help? Is the problem on my side, or in Azure?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do I have to call this endpoint? https://login.windows.net/common/openid/userinfo

Comment: Nobody can push me into the right direction?

Comment: Hi @Rymo are you still looking for the help

Comment: I recently got it all working! Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It will be helpful for other if you can post the answer which resolves your question.

Comment: You are right and actually it was just something small, always double check if the roles are properly set for the test users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roles where not set (for the test user) by party responsible for the claims part.